# System.LimitException: BMCServiceDesk:Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: rest, soql, remedy

I am invoking Remedyforce REST API 'Knowledgesearch' for searching Remedyforce Knowledge Base.
API Link - [here](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/remedyforce/201802/en/remedyforce-rest-api-801357497.html#RemedyforceRESTAPI-Knowledgesearch)

Since a week, I'm finding a strange behaviour while calling this API. I'm using Postman to call the REST API.

When I pass question: "What car can I have?", it returns a list of valid results.

However, when I pass the same question without '?'- "What car can I have", I get a message 'System.LimitException: BMCServiceDesk:Too many SOQL queries: 101'

Another such example is when I ask 'I want to go to the moon. could you please help?', I get the same error: 'System.LimitException: BMCServiceDesk:Too many SOQL queries: 101'

POST Body:

```
{   "SearchString": "what car can I have" }
```

OR

```
{   "SearchString": "I want to go to the moon. could you please help?" }
```

The complete JSON response is:

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
        "message": "System.LimitException: BMCServiceDesk:Too many SOQL queries: 101\n\n(BMCServiceDesk)\n\n\n\n\n"
    }
]
```

This behaviour has been consistent. I get this kind of response for some queries consistently, and for the rest, I get a list of results in response.

I have gone through these pages from Remedyforce describing this exception:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000181404&language=en_US&type=1
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

It speaks of SOQL query limits per transaction, but I don't see any limit exceeding happening in my case. I just get this response every time for certain queries, and for others, I don't.

Another strange behaviour is when I try the question - 'What car can I have?' from BMC Remedyforce UI, I get no results. When I run the same using API, I get many results.

Does anyone else face this issue?